# How to handle varchar columns with Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework

I have a table with a `varchar` column and I am using Entity Framework to use this column in the `WHERE` clause.

Entity Framework generates the query with `N''` hence the index on the column cannot be used. Is there a way to force Entity Framework to generate `varchar` query instead of `nvarchar` one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It actually depends on how you built your EF model, if you're using its Designer you can specify the required data type for each column (in your case simply set `varchar` and you're done).

If you're using a code-first approach you have to decorate the property that represents that column with the proper attribute (`string` objects in .NET are always Unicode so it'll map `nvarchar` by default), just do this (with data annotations, if you're using `StringAttribute` then se its `IsUnicode` property to `false`):

```
[Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
public string YourColumnName
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Comment: In the EDMX I have correctly set type (char) and length (6) for the column. I also added extra metadata class and decorated the property with Column(TypeName = "char")] and StringLength attributes. Yet I see the strange code executing SELECT TOP(2) and varchar(8000) for the parameter. How to fix it?

Comment: @Naomi not enough details to answer that. Post it as a new question and don't forget to include relevant part in your class declaration and code you execute to produce such SQL!

Comment: May be I'll add a new question tomorrow. I actually already asked this question in MSDN http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/696f5fd6-d10f-40d3-82d2-feea806965cc/two-same-classes-how-to-add-attributes-to-the-property?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: I used the fluent syntax in MyContext.OnModelCreating:`var myTable = modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntityType>();
myTable.Property(x => x.TextField).HasColumnType("varchar(8)");`

Answer (score 5):

You can use the EntityFunctions.AsNonUnicode(string) method, so then the EF will not pass the string value as nvarchar. I had the same issue with EF 5 and EDMX, where the Oracle database was ignoring a varchar2 column index, and that's worked for me.

```
var q = (from TableClass t in TableName
         where t.varchar2Column == EntityFunctions.AsNonUnicode(someText));
```

MSDN reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions(v=vs.110).aspx